# TwoWay Binding to XMLModel with button Custom Data property not updating model

Tags: xml, model, sapui5, two-way-binding

I have a very big problem updating the values of the `sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel`.

It is made of **TwoWay binding** to the **`XMLModel` and Custom Data** of the Button control.
Updating the Custom Data value in JS code does not update the `XMLModel`, and thus the button description, priority of List Item, etc. do not change. I have no idea anymore, so please help

Part of JS code where I update Custom Data (This is method called by button) - and this works:

```js
oEvent.getSource().data("Przeczytane", "true");
```

XML View:

```xml
<List items="{InfoNotif>/soap-env:Body/n0:ReadAdminMessageResponse/Dane/ListaKomunikatowAdministratora/KomunikatAdministratora}">
  <NotificationListItem
    title="{InfoNotif>Tytul/text()}"
    description="{InfoNotif>Opis/text()}"
    showCloseButton="false"
    datetime="{InfoNotif>DataPublikacji/text()}"
    unread="false"
    close=".onItemClose"
    authorName="{InfoNotif>IdUzytkownikaSystemu/text()}"
    authorPicture="sap-icon://group"
    priority="{=${InfoNotif>Przeczytano/text()}==='true' ? 'None' : 'High'}"
  >
    <buttons>
      <Button
        text="{=${InfoNotif>Przeczytano/text()}==='true' ? 'Oznacz jako nieprzeczytane' : 'Oznacz jako przeczytane'}"
        type="Accept"
        app:IdKomunikatuAdmin="{InfoNotif>IdKomunikatu/text()}"
        app:IdProcesuAdmin="{InfoNotif>/****/IdKomunikatu/text()}"
        app:Przeczytane="{
          path: 'InfoNotif>Przeczytano',
          mode: 'sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay',
          type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String'
        }"
        press=".onAcceptInfoPress"
      />
    </buttons>
  </NotificationListItem>
</List>
```

Result is:

- Custom Data new value set correct
- value in `XMLModel` **NOT SET**
- other controls binding to `/Przeczytano/text()` **not updated**

Comment: What's that weird syntax `${InfoNotif>Przeczytano/text()}==='true'`?

Comment: Expression binding

Comment: I would have written `${InfoNotif>Przeczytano}`. What is `text()` doing? What does your model look like?

Comment: Model is simple XML file from $ajax query.

text() is from here: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/02/usage-of-client-side-xml-model-in-sapui5/
This tag looks like this:
<Przeczytano>true</Przeczytano>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with an `XMLModel` before but I tried to create [a small sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/KeViOAS6M8WLlxlu?preview).

Just modify the `Input` in the first column or press the `Button` in the second column to see the effect.

It seems like two way binding works (better) if you remove the `text()` statement (and then it also looks more like the other models, making it easier to replace it with JSON/OData).

Then I extended the sample to see if the model can be modified in JS code. And (just like with regular models) it works best if you modify the model using `setProperty` and don't try to modify the controls directly.

If you use `oBindingContext.getObject(...)` to access a property you have to add `text()` to the path (`oContext.getObject("text1/text()")`) or read the `textContent` from the result (`oContext.getObject("text1").textContent`). This also makes it harder to replace it with a JSON/ODataModel so I used `oModel.getProperty(...)` instead.